# MKV, MP4, or FLV for web video streaming

Tags: web, video-streaming, containers, aac, apache-modules

I'm currently on edge with what container I should use for the videos I put on my website.

I recently started uploaded videos of game play/walkthroughs and saw the need for a container that could hold HD video without limitations on file size, codecs (AAC or AVC), or resolution (in the future I want to be able to support 5K video) and 5.1 Dolby digital and up audio. Of course I don't expect the 5K to be efficient at being streamed, I just want it to be available.

This is where the confusion started.

I currently use the .flv container because people state it is all around better. Less resource consumptive, widely used, and supports the common codecs. The problem with this is simple. It cannot support the HD content I want to show: 5.1 dolby audio and limitless file size.

MP4 is everything I need, but I heard that it can be slow to respond, pseudostreaming modules are not widely accepted by browsers, and I don't have time to change containers everytime someone wants to update to .mp5, 6, 12, etc.

That's where I am including .mkv as the container. .MKV also supports everything I want (HD, 3D), all codecs, universal, and limitless file attributes. THE ONLY problem is that it cannot be streamed.

I know this is a programmers site, but may be in the future, being that we can only advance web connections, I or someone else could program a module for apache .mkv streaming. I'm don't know where an apache module source is, so I cannot do it at this time.

I leaning between .flv and .mkv. I'm not really concerned about .mp4 because if I want to be future-proof I need .mkv, if I'm not concerned about the future or updates I should stay with .flv.

What do you all think. Would it really be so difficult to program a .mkv streaming module?

Excluding web streaming, which of the 3 would be all around better. Video quality (AAC AVC), file size limits, universal, web support, etc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window media streaming platform. After that they will look after your every problem. However ,MP4 with h264 video and aac audio and streamed/played with flash is also good.

Comment: I'm actually doing some research on writing browser extensions. The extension will allow other browsers to view mkv video. Also plan on making a simple mkv web player and researching Apache modules for streaming video.